# Не понимаю за MVC. Как разобраться?

Tags: php, mvc

Поясните, пожалуйста, как это работает. Если можно, то с простым примером. Вроде и понимаю что это, но не понимаю, зачем это надо ? Зачем отправлять из модели данные во вьюшку ? Почему нельзя отправить ответ с контроллера ?

Вот тут автор говорит о том, что MVC в принципе г*но
https://anton-pribora.ru/articles/php/mvc/

Вот тут вообще неясно, накой ляд нужно в модель пихать то, что хорошо себя чувствует в контроллере..И на каждом сайте описание MVC изложено по своему. Может хоть здесь опытные рассудят ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему ты думаешь, что тут опытные?)) И что ответ даст тебе именно опытный. И как поймёшь, что ответ верный, если другие ответы ты считаешь не верными?)) И почему думаешь, что опытный не напишет какую-то свою чушь видения mvc?)))

Comment: Знаю одного опытного кстати, опыт у него больше 20 лет. Он тоже считает что ООП и MVC не нужно :))

Comment: "накой ляд нужно в модель пихать то, что хорошо себя чувствует в контроллере"  --- например что?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну я работал в проекте, где "ООП" был реализован через процедурный стиль. Работает и ладно ). Но за MVC хочу разобраться. Просто чтобы спать спокойно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Работа с БД. Почему я не могу запросы в контроллере описывать ? Почему не могу валидацию делать в контроллере ? И т.п.

Comment: Контроллер - это вещь, которая что-то контролирует. Логично, да?))  И если округлить, то он контролирует процесс, инициируемый из вне (например пользователем). Как надзиратель, прораб, раздаёт всем работу, принимает результат  и отдаёт клиенту. Поэтому в нём (точнее в его методах) ничего лишнего быть не должно. Он должен принять запрос, раздать всем указания, связать кого-то с кем-то (например забрать из сервиса пользователей дату рождения и кинуть в сервис расчёта сколько дней прошло с указанной даты). и вернуть результат работы запроса.

Comment: @sousage1212, не переживай по этому поводу, с опытом всё поймешь. Читай лучшие практики, анализируй, делай выводы и всё станет яснее. На твой вопрос нет ответа и быть не может. ИМХО.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ну так это понятно, я не понимаю где тут нужен view и модель..обработаю я в контроллере все, что мне надо..ну и верну ответ клиенту с данными. Или это и есть по факту view ?

Comment: А у автора статьи проблема в том, что он не работал с большими крупными проектами, поэтому не знает что с этим всем делать.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не знаю за автора статьи..просто грустно от того, что ты выполняешь любое ТЗ, что дают на собеседовании, но валишься, когда спрашивают за MVC и почему я не использовал его в своем решении задачи.

Comment: @sousage1212 ну так надо обосновывать значит)) если например страница - лендинг - то там mvc будет использовать только умолишённый)) Если это простой сайт-визитка, то там тоже можно не использовать mvc просто потому, что это излишнее усложнение. Но правильно подключить файлы всё же надо)) надо принимать решения на основе входных данных. А говорить ВСЕГДА НАДО ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ MVC!  или наоборот - это глупо с любой стороны

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так обосновываю ) Нахрена мне MVC для формы обратной связи ? А для парсера статей с википедии ? Либо HR дурные, либо я чего-то не понимаю

Comment: Ответьте мне на такой вопрос. Допустим в методе одного контроллера вы запихнули всё что нужно и отдали пользователю страницу html (запрос через GET). Потом вам срочно понадобилось отправить туже самую информацию, но на почту и в файле (метод POST). Вы создадите ещё один метод в контроллере и продублируете код?

Comment: @ArchDemon Я бы сделал обычный шаблон, который извлекает get параметр и формирует необходимую информацию. И это будет отлично работать. Для почты либо использовал бы библиотеку, либо собственный класс. Отправлял бы в его метод данные типа email, content и всё. Зачем отправлять на почту целую страницу - не понимаю.. Где дублирование кода в таком случае - тоже не понимаю

Comment: Меня не интересует каким образом вы отправите письмо. Меня интересует как вы сформируете текст html с учётом того, что шаблон у вас есть, но он принимает GET, а не POST. Возможно, у вас шаблон ещё и сам рендерит данные.